# Large number of Custom Taxonomy WordPress freezes database and entire website

Tags: mysql, wordpress, performance, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I have imported 100 thousands of custom Taxonomy terms in my WordPress database. I have imported Country -> State -> Cities hierarchically. By this my database tables terms(20 mb) and taxonomy terms(15mb) have been this much bigger that my whole website and admin panel has gone down and can't even load a single page of my website. I have also tried elasticPress, Jetpack which could not help me for my this issue. Basically I want to import at least 5 countries with its states and cities into my database, so user can choose it's location with a drill down drop-down approach. 
Could you please help me anyone? Can I cache this or how can I do this without affecting the performance of mysql database? I can give you more information about it. Please ask me anything. Thank you. 
PS: I have been hosting my this website on CloudWays

Comment: It strikes me that if you want your users to drill down into hierarchy of location data there are other ways that do not burden your WP database with such a huge number of entries. Have you considered Google Places API where you can use Google's API to pull location info on the fly and then just store the selection made by the user as a custom value?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But the way the theme  working is that it's using drill-down approach in adding new products and searching in front website. It seems quite difficult to change entire structure.

Answer (score 0):

WP uses the EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) schema model.  This is rather clumsy and it does not scale well past 'thousands'.

There is, however, a partial fix by improving the "meta" schemas in WP:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

The 'real' fix is to design your own schema with columns for attributes, not reaching indirectly to find them.

There is not a real good reason to have Country->State->City be a hierarchy.  A flat table with those 3 columns (and maybe some other stuff) is faster and less clumsy.  Other Taxonomies may need to be stored hierarchically.  Would you like to discuss a specific one.

MySQL 8 has a new feature: CTEs.  They make it easier to write queries to traverse hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

Create a REST API to output your post instead of normal php. It will load your post faster. Take advantage of this Wordpress function `register_rest_route()`